# Multiply normalized values - How to take the weighted average of words

Tags: python, file, python-2.7, normalization, multiplication

I  have two files in the following format:

File 1:

```
 TOPIC:topic_0 24
 track 0.25000000000000000
 record 0.25000000000000000
 athlete 0.25000000000000000  
 run 0.25000000000000000
 star 0.0
 film 0.0
 TOPIC:topic_1 0
 run 0.0  
 track 0.0
 athlete 0.0
 record 0.0
 star 0.0
 film 0.0 
 TOPIC:topic_2 20
 film 0.25000000000000000
 star 0.25000000000000000
 track 0.25000000000000000
 record 0.25000000000000000
 athlete 0.0
 run 0.0
```

File 2:

```
0.25 0.5 0.25
```

I then wanted to compute the weights for each of the words. For example, the weight of the word "record" would be:

```
record (0.25*0.25) + (0*0.5) + (0.25*0.25) which is 0.125.
```

That is, in File 1, word record is present in topic 0, 1 and 2. So, the 0th position 1st, 2nd position value from File 2 is taken and multiplied with the respective weights of the words present in topic 0, 1 and 2. I used the code:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby, imap

d = defaultdict(list)
with open("file1.txt") as f, open("file2.txt") as f2:
    values = map(float, f2.read().split()) 
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() and not line.startswith("TOPIC"):
            name, val = line.split()
            d[name].append(float(val))

for k,v in d.items():
     print("{} {}".format(k ,sum(i*j for i, j in zip(v,values)) ))
```

I am getting the Output as:

```
 run 0.0625
 track 0.125
 athlete 0.0625
 record 0.125
 star 0.0625
 film 0.0625
```

**The output column when summed should give 1.**   (**Sorry this sample data is bad as it won't sum up to 1 due to the values taken. But in the actual data, after multiplication **when the output file's 2nd column is summed, it should give 1**)** I am getting the sum somewhere between 0.95 to 0.99 but not exactly 1.

Both File1 and File2 are normalized. That is, the sum of values of file2 is equal to 1 and each of the topic sum like total weight values of each of the topic is equal to 1.

When the multiplication happens, the end result is also supposed to sum up to 1. The data I have shown is just a sample. My actual data runs to about 1000s of topics.

We can see that all words are present in all topics. And, here the topic 1 is totally 0. All the words have no weights.

This above code works fine when all the topics have words with some weights. When the total topic (like topic_2) is zero, then my output is not summing up to 1.

The example I have taken is simple and it won't sum up to 1 as the numbers are such. But, for the data I have it should sum up to 1.

**Can I rectify this or is there a better way of coding (than shown above) to multiply the values for the words?**

Comment: I don't see any normalization here, in the code or the data. Some topics do add up to 1, but `topic_1` does not, and the values in File 2 do not.

Comment: No, the data I have taken is just a sample. The actual data is so huge. In that, both the files have normalized values. So, when I multiply it should automatically sum up to 1. We needn't normalize it in the code. But, since there are empty topics like topic_2 here, I guess that is causing some confusion. When there are non zero topics in the entire input data file, then the code works fine.

Comment: Well, for a mcve, you should normalize the sample data too.

Comment: the second column of the output data should sum up to 1 after multiplication. The sample input data (file1 and file2) is normalized. Each topic individually sums up to 1 and the total values of file2 also gives 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say **each of the topic sum like total weight values of each of the topic is equal to 1**, but this is not the case.

Since everything in `topic_1` is zero, it might as well not be there. So the `0.5` in the second column of File 2 might as well not be there either; it gets zeroed out in the multiplication. So, effectively, the total of File 2 is `0.25 + 0.25 = 0.5`, which is the total you're getting.

Since your real data is summing to about `0.99`, and this only happens when one or more topics are all zero, I'm going to guess that the difference between `1` and the total you're getting is equal to the sum of the weights that are being zeroed out, just as in this example. Look for that.

Comment: I understand that, but the values in my actual data are such that irrespective of the topics being zero they should sum up to 1. I am getting somewhere close to 0.95 and 0.99. But not exactly 1.

Comment: Then you need to refine your mcve to reflect what's happening with your real data. How else is anyone going to figure it out? Note that in the process of doing that, you're quite likely to figure it out yourself.

Comment: Since only when the topics values (like more than 500 topics) are huge, I get empty topics. For small topic values (less than 200)  I do not get empty topics. So, I am not able to post my actual data here :(

Comment: @Sanathana - see revision.

Comment: It is confusing.. any ideas of how to modify this code to multiply efficiently? I am trying this out since yesterday and still it is not working :( I tried for 1000 topics. More than 100 topics were empty in that and I am getting my outputs somewhere between 0.95 to 0.99 there as well.

Comment: @Sanathana: Yes, it **is** confusing, and I'm not terribly inclined to spend any more time on it. See if the total of the zeroed-out weights accounts for the difference. If it doesn't, then look at your code and your data and your question again, and edit your question to clearly explain what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your time and valuable suggestions :)